# Javascript to turn Barcode scanner output of multiline buffer to array or json

Tags: javascript, buffer, barcode-scanner

Good Morning!

I'm trying to get a USB Barcode scan into a single array or even better yet a JSON object, but I can't figure out how to turn this multi-character buffer into an object.

Below is the Raw HID stream coming from the Scan (Zebra LS2208)

```
<Buffer 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 23 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 22 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 22 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 23 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 1e 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 23 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

And when I turn it into characters, it's outputted like so:

```
7

6

5

7

5

6

9

3

1

2

6

7
```

Now these are the numbers in the UPC, but I've been having a hard time turn this into an array or object because each of these new lines (including the spaces) are seen as a new array.

What I ultimately want this turned into is either:
`[7,6,5,7,5,6,9,3,1,2,6,7]`
OR

```
{
 "upc": "765756931267"
}
```

This is the very basic code I'm using:

```
var KeyboardCharacters = require('node-hid-stream').KeyboardCharacters;
var characters = new KeyboardCharacters({ vendorId: 1504, productId: 4608 });

characters.on("data", function(data) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Is anyone able to offer any insight? Would love the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else comes around and has a similar problem, I found the solution to my problem.

With the USB Scanner I was using, a Zebra LS2208, it comes with multiple scanning modes which can be set by scanning a bar code. Over the last day, I've been using it as **USB Keyboard (HID)** which means each digit in the UPC was a different Key Down/Key Up, which this morning dawned on me.

I scanned the bar code which switched it's scanning mode to **IBM HAND-HELD USB** and attempted the scan, but I received an error in the code. I didn't change any code and the path of the device was the same, but to double check the device settings, I used the following, which is part of [**node-hid**](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) to check my device settings:

```
var devices = HID.devices();
console.log(devices);
```

I noticed that the *vendorId* was the same, but the *productId* had changed... I updated the ID in the code, re-scanned and voila, one Buffer was outputted and a simple `toString()` changed it to the correct numbers.

Beyond the Buffer fix, I also stopped using the NPM package which inherited [**node-hid**](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) and I just used it myself and wrote whatever else I needed.

Code fragment of the fix:

```
// Use the serialport module to get scanner  data
var HID = require('node-hid');

// Set the device we're using for Scanning Barcodes
var device = new HID.HID('/dev/hidraw0');

// Register a scanned UPC and start the rest of the program process
device.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Scan prompted');
    console.log('UPC = ' + data.toString());
});
```